# Installing numpy in qpython

Tags: numpy, qpython, qpython3

I've been trying to install additional libraries on qpython.  Unfortunately the documentation I've found so far is very sparse (e. g. http://wiki.qpython.org/doc/install-libraries/).
It says you can install libraries on pip console but it doesn't explain anywhere what that means, neither how to access pip console etc.

The second option is to add the library into the following folder: /sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python3.2/site-packages (For QPython3)

This second option seems straight forward to me, yet how do I get the correct library (e. g. on github etc.)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Click the package button on the home page, then you can install numpy with qpypi! :)

Hope this help! :)

Answer (score 1):

start qpython on your android device, once it's running, click on the python icon in the middle of the screen, a menu will pop up asking if you'd like to do one of three things, run scrip, start project, or do something with a QR Code. choose "run scrip" and it will open up another menu, then select pip_install.py

the script will start and then you can type "pip install (numpy) or what ever module you want to install. Not really sure why that's the process, but it just is. I've been getting errors trying to install numpy and matplotlib so i'm still trying to figure it out.

it was way easier on my windows system.

Comment: The problem is that this standard procedure does not work for numpy or matplotlib, which is what brought me here

Answer (score 1):

I just installed numpy-qpython by going to libraries, Qpypi, and selecting numpy-qpython. Looks like the full numpy isn't compatible with qpython

Answer (score 0):

1) Install [QPython](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy).

2) Install [AIPY](https://1f6ff81c-play-google-com.tvp.qa.thumbtribe.co.za/store/apps/details?id=org.aipy.app) for QPython.

3) Then go to QPython-->QPYPI-->AIPY and install from there Numpy, SciPy, Matplotlib, etc.