# is there a version of numpy that is compatible with qpython3 and if so how do I download it

Tags: numpy, qpython3

I have recently started some development with qpython3 for android and would like to utilize numpy in the code implementation.  I have tried to install numpy through the following code process

```
intall pip
pip.main(['install','numpy])
```

however, when the code runs the command, I get an error informing me that I must have python 2.7 or python 3.4 installed.  It looks as if it tries to install a version of numpy that was meant for an actual python3 installation and not qpython.  I also tried navigating to http://qpypi.qpython.org to download the zip file directly, but when I clicked on the link for numpy-qpython, nothing happens.

Comment: A difficulty with `numpy` is that contains a lot of compiled code.  It isn't pure Python.  So someone has to either create the necessary binaries, or arrange to compile them on your machine.  Is this the `android` `qpython3`?

Comment: Searching on your 2 tags yields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380424/installing-numpy-in-qpython

Comment: I had already seen those two stack overflow posts and none of them provide answers that work.